# RegEx Replace with character substitution in captured group

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net, regexp-replace

I can get the string of my interest using regex, but how do I replace it with a character substituted in the capture?

I want to remove the `>` character from inside any html attribute, or replace it with `&gt;`.

**Sample original string**

```
<html> 
<head></head> 
<body> 
<div  sometag="abc>def" onclick="myfn()" class='xyz'>
Dear {@CustomerName},
blah blah blah
</div></body> 
</html>
```

**Desired result**

```
<html> 
<head></head> 
<body> 
<div  sometag="abc&gt;def" onclick="myfn()" class='xyz'>
Dear {@CustomerName},
blah blah blah
</div></body> 
</html>
```

I'm using the following regex pattern and replacement

**Pattern**: `\s\w+\s*=\s*(['"])[^\1]+?\1`

**Replacement**: `-- don't know! what should I use? --`

This is my `vb.net` code (just in case if it helps)

```
Dim reAttr As New Regex("\s\w+\s*=\s*(['""])[^\1]+?\1", RegexOptions.Singleline)
result = reAttr.Replace(text, Replace("$&", ">", ""))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
Dim reAttr As New Regex("\s\w+\s*=\s*(['""])(?:(?!\1).)*?\1", RegexOptions.Singleline)
Dim result = reAttr.Replace(text, New MatchEvaluator(Function(m As Match)
         Return m.Value.Replace(">", "-")
     End Function))
```

Note that `[^\1]` is not doing what you expect, it matches any char but a SOH char (`\x01`). The `(?:(?!\1).)*?` [tempered greedy token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30900794/tempered-greedy-token-what-is-different-about-placing-the-dot-before-the-negat) does what you wanted, it matches any char, other than the value captured in Group 1, 0 or more times, as few times as possible.

The `MatchEvaluator` is used as the replacement arguments where you may access the whole match value with `m.Value`.

Comment: works perfectly! thank you so much. I wasted one full day on this. Also, the `[\1]` was selecting the part of string that I was expecting, so got confused with it. thanks for correcting that too.