# Replace match in Regex

Tags: regex, vb.net

My function gets a string and iterates through the lines of a XML file. If the match contains the "**<**" character, it should replace it with "**test**", but it doesnt work. No changes.
How can I replace a character inside a match?

```vb
Public Function DelEscapeCharacters(ByVal src As String) As String
    Try
        Dim matches = Regex.Matches(src, "(?<=<rrm:title>)(.*?)(?=</rrm:title>)")

        For Each m As Match In matches
            Regex.Replace(src, "<", "test")
        Next

        Return src

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Function
```

Even when I try to use a MatchEvaluator, is doesn't work.

```
  Public Function DelEscapeCharacters(ByVal src As String) As String
            Try 
                Dim matches = Regex.Matches(src, "(?<=<rrm:title>)(.*?)(?=</rrm:title>)")
    
                For Each m As Match In matches
                    Regex.Replace(src, "<", New MatchEvaluator(AddressOf ChangeChar))
                Next
    
                Return src
                Catch ex As Exception
    
            End Try
        End Function



 

    Function ChangeChar(ByVal match As Match) As String
            ' Get string from match.
            Dim v As String = match.ToString()
            Select Case v
                Case "<"
                    Return "&lt;"
                Case ">"
                    Return "&gt;"
                Case """"
                    Return "&quot;"
                Case "'"
                    Return "&apos;"
                Case "&"
                    Return "&amp;"
            End Select
    
        End Function
```

Comment: `Regex.Replace` does not modify the string. Assign the result to the variable. Better, use the `MatchEvaluator` inside `Regex.Replace`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61684616/3832970).

Comment: Regex is not good in parsing nested structures. Use [XDocument.Parse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xdocument.parse) or [XElement.Parse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xelement.parse) and work with the data model.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes This doesn't work, because the regex is not valid at this time, because of the special characters. This is the reason, I use regex.